# Erro no insert com PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Olá,

Estou com o seguinte codigo:

```
public function insert($nome,$email,$senha,$cluster,$situacoes_id,$niveis_acesso_id,$empresa,$modified,$area,$escritorio,$contrato,$regional) {        

       $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO [dbo].Usuarios VALUES('$nome','$email','$senha','$cluster','$situacoes_id','$niveis_acesso_id',
       '$empresa','$modified','$area','$escritorio','$contrato','$regional')");

       $stmt->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
       $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
       $stmt->bindParam(':senha', $senha);
       $stmt->bindParam(':cluster', $cluster);
       $stmt->bindParam(':situacoes_id', $situacoes_id);
       $stmt->bindParam(':niveis_acesso_id', $niveis_acesso_id);
       $stmt->bindParam(':empresa', $empresa);
       $stmt->bindParam(':modified', $modified);
       $stmt->bindParam(':area', $area);
       $stmt->bindParam(':escritorio', $escritorio);    
       $stmt->bindParam(':contrato', $contrato);    
       $stmt->bindParam(':regional', $regional);    
       $stmt->execute();

       var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());

       if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo "cadastro com sucesso";
    }
    else {
        echo "não foi cadastrado";
    }



}
```

esta reportando esse erro:

> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "IMSSP" [1]=> int(-29) [2]=> string(84) "Tried to bind parameter number 0. SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters." } não foi cadastrado

Comment: Pelo que diz o Erro "O SQL Server suporta no máximo 2100 parâmetros."... Você está tentando inserir um valor muito grande no banco.

Comment: Já verifiquei os dados editando o insert separamento no Sql Server e funciona, no código que não esta funcionando.

Comment: Encontrei uma coisa aqui, tente o seguinte: `INSERT INTO [dbo].Usuarios VALUES($nome,$email,$senha,$cluster,$situacoes_id,$niveis_acesso_id,
       $empresa,$modified,$area,$escritorio,$contrato,$regional)`, talvez retirando os ' funcione.

Comment: Constrói o texto da query de forma similar a: INSERT INTO [dbo].Usuarios (nome, email, ...outros_campos) values (:nome, :email, ...:outros_campos)

Comment: Você percebeu que você define os valores dos parâmetros, mas em nenhum momento você os utiliza na SQL? Você utilizou as variáveis diretamente ao invés de utilizar os parâmetros.

Comment: Não entendi, não estou utilizando na SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua query está escrita errada:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO [dbo].Usuarios VALUES('$nome','$email','$senha','$cluster','$situacoes_id','$niveis_acesso_id',
       '$empresa','$modified','$area','$escritorio','$contrato','$regional')");
```

Os parâmetros num prepared statement devem iniciar com dois-pontos e as aspas simples são desnecessárias, mesmo em campos char:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO [dbo].Usuarios VALUES(:nome,:email,:senha,:cluster,:situacoes_id,:niveis_acesso_id,
       :empresa,:modified,:area,:escritorio,:contrato,:regional)");
```

Comment: Show de bola Júlio, funcionou!!!